# C# return a variable as read only from get; set;

Tags: c#, properties, readonly

I swear I have seen an example of this but have been googling for a bit and can not find it.

I have a class that has a reference to an object and need to have a GET; method for it.  My problem is that I do not want anyone to be able to fiddle with it, i.e. I want them to get a read only version of it, (note I need to be able to alter it from within my class).

Thanks

Comment: I am amazed at how many people misunderstood the question. Jon Skeet and Anton Gogolev got it right.

Comment: I didn't think I misunderstood - but still got down voted - oh well

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I don't think Anton Gogolev is on topic here. And for Jon - well he just gets things right:)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, there's no way of doing this. For instance, if you return a `List<string>` (and it's not immutable) then callers *will* be able to add entries.

The normal way round this is to return an immutable wrapper, e.g. [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

For other mutable types, you may need to clone the value before returning it.

Note that just returning an immutable interface view (e.g. returning `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`) won't stop a caller from casting back to the mutable type and mutating.

EDIT: Note that apart from anything else, this kind of concern is one of the reasons why immutable types make it easier to reason about code :)

Comment: First you say it cannot be done and then you point to the cloning solution. Also, maybe cloning is a new idea for c#, but it's been there for a long while in c++, for example. It also isn't strictly cloning - it is creating a copy of internal data and returning this copy, not the original data - the copy doesn't have to be the same type as the original.

Answer (score 6):

Return a reference to a stripped-down interface:

```
 interface IFoo
   string Bar { get; }

 class ClassWithGet
   public IFoo GetFoo(...);
```

Comment: Ideally including a `private` or `internal` implementation of IFoo so that it cannot be cast back ;)

Comment: Hum no, if the Interface is internal or Private you won't be able to return a Public member that has a non accessible type. This won't compile : "Inconsistent accessibility: field type ... is less accessible than field ..."

Answer (score 4):

If the object isn't too complicated/extensive then write an wrapper around it.

for example:

```
class A {
    public string strField = 'string';
    public int intField = 10;
}

class AWrapper {
    private A _aObj;

    public AWrapper(A aobj) {
      _aObj = A;
    }

    public string strField {
         get {
            return _aObj.strField;
         }
    }

    public int intField {
         get {
            return _aObj.intField;
         }
    }
}
```

So now all you do is give your client code an instance of the AWrapper class so that they may only use what you allow them to see.

this may get a bit complicated and may not scale well if your base class is not set in stone, but for most simple situation it may just do the trick. I think this is called a facade pattern(but don't quote me on that =) )

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for.

I should also add, that even if the object you want to wrap is complex, it doesn't mean you have to actually wrap every method/function. In my case, I just wanted to wrap a very complex object and only showcase certain methods.

For example, your complex object can have 20 methods, but your wrapped object only gives access to 5.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. Get and set accessors to reference types get and set the reference to the object. You can prevent changes to the reference by using a private (or internal) setter, but you cannot prevent changes to the object itself if it's exposed by a getter.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can return a copy of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Your question reads like you're looking for:

```
public PropertyName { get; private set; }
```

But then, given the answers so far I'm not sure I'm interpreting your question correctly. Besides, who am I to question Jon Skeet? :)

Comment: That returns a reference that is read only, since it can't be assigned, but you can still edit the object because it's properties aren't read only

Comment: This helped me! What a clever way to keep something public but not writable

Answer (score 0):

i agree with  ReadOnlyCollection

See my simple code:

```
 private List<Device> _devices;
public readonly System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Device> Devices 
{
 get
 { 
return (_devices.AsReadOnly());
 }
```

}

ReadOnlyCollection dosen't has Add method so user cant add properties to it.BUT ther is no warranty that if user can modify objects by calling their methods....

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem in a certain way. 
I have a CategoryViewModel class, which have a property Category that I want private read-only :

```
public CategoryViewModel
{
    private Category { get; }

}
```

In fact, I want it to be exported as read-only to other class. However I can't do such thing.
In my case (maybe it will help some other guys), I want to add it to a repository. The only way that I've found is to have a function with the repository as param 1, and an Action as param 2 :

```
public void ApplyAction(ICategoryRepository repo, Action<ICategoryRepository, Category> action)
{
    action(repo, Category);
}
```

Like that, from elsewhere, I can do such thing :

```
 categoryViewModel.ApplyAction(_repository, (r, c) => r.MarkForInsertOrUpdate(c));
```

This can help other to expose there property only for certains cases and can manage them.