# C# return non-modifiable list

Tags: c#, .net, properties, readonly, modifier

I have a class which contains a `List<Item>` I have a getter on the class that returns this. Is there some thing I can do to ensure the user who calls cannot modify the returned List? (Since it's a reference type - I believe changes to the returned reference would affect the list stored in the source object)

Comment: If you loosen the restriction that you must actually return a List, you can simply return `IEnumerable<T>`, which has `.Count()` and `.ElementAt()` methods that perform at O(1) speed if your enumerated collection implements `IList<T>`.  In this case, the user can only get at the list if they explicitly cast it, which would be a violation of your public contract.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return your List wrapped in [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

```
  public ReadOnlyCollection<Item> MyROList {
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Item>(myList); }
  }

  private List<Item> myList = new List<Item>();
```

More details [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939563/c-return-a-variable-as-read-only-from-get-set).

Depending on usage of your class, you could allocate the `ReadOnlyCollection` at construction time and link it to the underlying `List`. If you expect to always or most of the time need this property, and the underlying `List` is in place at that time, then this is sensible. Otherwise you could leave the `ReadOnlyCollection<Item>` class member `null` and allocate it on demand in the getter if it is `null` (taking thread safety into account).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't it be better to wrap the collection in a ReadOnlyCollection in the constructor - so that its done just once, rather than doing it each time. Of course my object is a bit heavier - since I have an extra member. But probably better than creating new objects each time?

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection is a live copy of the source collection. When the source collection changes, the ReadOnlyCollection changes too.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want any changes *your* class makes in the future to be reflected in the returned list? If so, simply

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(list);
```

would be fine.

However, if you want to return a collection which *nothing* will modify in the future (i.e. a completely independent copy of the original list) you might want to use:

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(list.ToList());
```

(Using LINQ's `ToList` method is a very simple way of cloning a list.)

Note that if the list's element type is a mutable reference type, changes to the data within the referenced objects would still be visible to everyone, of course.

Comment: `list.AsReadOnly()` / `list.ToList().AsReadOnly()` are terse alternatives for `List<T>`. For a general `IList<T>`, the constructor for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is probably the best option.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the example. It's good to know ToList can be used to clone a list.

Comment: @Jon: Wouldn't it be better to wrap the collection in a ReadOnlyCollection in the constructor - so that its done just once, rather than doing it each time. Of course my object is a bit heavier - since I have an extra member. But probably better than creating new objects each time? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ani: I think it's good to return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` - and make that explicit in the API - to make it absolutely clear that the caller can't add items to it. It would be nice if there were an interface representing a read-only list, but there isn't :(

Comment: @aip.cd.aish: It's a pretty light-weight object, but it depends on how often it's going to be called, I guess. It feels a little odd to have another field for this, but in some cases it *could* make sense, yes.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Don't understand your point; `List<T>.AsReadOnly()` creates and returns a `new ReadOnlyCollection<T>.` Its return type is `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, not `IList<T>`, so no casting is required to "make that explicit in the API." Or have I misunderstood? I do agree about the lack of an interface for read-only collections though.

Comment: @Ani: Ah, I missed that. Yes, in that case that's fine :)

Comment: @Jon: I just realized what you meant in your last sentence! That is a very good point. Did not realize that. The object that is accessed through the readonly list is still modifiable.

Comment: @aip.cd.aish: Just remember that the list doesn't contain objects - it contains *references*. .NET doesn't have the idea of a "read-only reference to a mutable object" or anything really similar.